# Jupyter gives LSTM algo result, then it gives out Keras.Modules errors with SAME code

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook

I am using Anaconda and Python 3.8 and have Tensorflow 2.5 and Keras 2.4.3 and I am getting this error below but only sometimes when running the EXACT SAME LSTM algo in Jupyter:

```
AttributeError                            
Traceback (most recent call 

AttributeError: module 'keras.utils.generic_utils' has no attribute ‘populate_dict_with_module_objects'
```

I’ve read on here the suggestions and tried a few Mac Terminal pip instructions to get the versions to reconcile but what I don’t understand is why using the SAME LSTM algo, it works sometimes and other times it produces the error code above.

Has anyone ever come across this issue before?

Comment: Keras 2.4.x does not support TensorFlow 2.5, that is why you get an error

Comment: Thanks Dr Snoopy, I had read that and yet the LSTM script did work initially when I opened a new notebook? (Without changing any s/ware, I ran it again an hour later and got errors). Going to TensorFlow 2.4 gives me this error ---> Pls see Dropbox image of short error code: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ccrot3s541hh47g/tensorflow.png

Thanks,

Comment: How do I resolve this and which version of Keras, TensorFlow and Anaconda what do I need for everything to be compatible? I used PIP Terminal commands and also installed s/ware via Anaconda -- could that be a problem?

Comment: @Bard,Can you try with `Keras 2.5.0rc0` and Tensorflow `2.5.0`?

Comment: Cheers for the suggestion TFer2. 
I now have Keras 2.5.0rc0 (and TensorFlow 2.5) but get this error? Pls see Dropbox image of short error code: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/zkgypd4e4bboe4b/ltm2%20keras%20fail.png
and
https://www.dropbox.com/s/39gmscbvxgecu3w/ltm3%20keras%20fail.png

Comment: If possible could someone please tell me what exactly versions of Anaconda, Keras and TensorFlow actually work together because I can't remember the last time I wasted this much time trying to configure s/ware to work.

The fact that the LSTM algo worked initially and then threw up errors later seems to suggest that incompatibility should have been occurring from the very first moment I ran the program and yet it did work. So how can an incompatible  Keras 2.4.3 ever work with Tensorflow 2.5, which it did initially?

Comment: @Bard, without changing any version, here simple workaround is instead of `from keras.*` replace with `from tensorflow.keras.*`. For example `from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential`, `from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM`. Can you try and let us know?

Comment: Great, thanks @TFer2 for getting back to me. 

I added tensorflow into those two lines you cited above so they now read as tensorflow.keras.models etc but I get a longer error message (including a Yahoo Finance read error, the source of data that I am applying the LSTM algo to)?

Pls see errors here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4xof0gr84pyr0c6/ltm2%20keras%20%28i%29.png

https://www.dropbox.com/s/rzmec4uhfc55n3c/ltm2%20keras%20fail%20%28ii%29.png 

Thanks once again.

Comment: @Bard, First of all above error is not related to Tensorflow. It looks like a temporary error at the Remote Data end which Yahoo will fix soon.Thanks!

Comment: Hi @TFer2 My ML code is still showing a Yahoo Finance error, it's still down two weeks later (tried today)? This code only stopped working when I followed the above instructions and the Yahoo url does work even with the correct dates if you paste it? Tried many other companies and they all have Yahoo errors? Chances are unlikely....

Comment: @Bard Please note that people will answer the question that is asked in your question, not other errors that might be coming now that your initial issue is solved. You can ask a new question for your new issue, which is different than the original issue in this question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to solve the above error **"AttributeError: module 'keras.utils.generic_utils' has no attribute ‘populate_dict_with_module_objects'"**

By installing TensorFlow & Keras upgrading versions. It should solve your problem.

- To upgrade TensorFlow version

```
!pip install tensorflow --upgrade --user
```

- To upgrade Keras version

```
!pip install keras --upgrade --user
```

Comment: Thanks udara, I used both commands. TF is now upgraded to 2.5.0.

"Successfully installed gast-0.4.0 grpcio-1.34.1 h5py-3.1.0 install-1.3.4 tensorflow-2.5.0 tensorflow-estimator-2.5.0"

With Keras I got a lots of lines stating: "already satisfied" in my Apple Terminal.

When I run the code I am now getting a Yahoo Finance data reader error which I've never had before? 
Pls see two images:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/4xof0gr84pyr0c6/ltm2%20keras%20%28i%29.png

https://www.dropbox.com/s/rzmec4uhfc55n3c/ltm2%20keras%20fail%20%28ii%29.png

Cheers,

Comment: Hi 

Can anyone resolve this s/w which has never worked since I downloaded & tried different versions & why there is an error message nearly a month later from Yahoo? 

The urls's work when you go to them manually & I  doubt all Yahoo historic data (as I've tried different companies stock symbols) is not working after nearly a month.

The Yahoo issue (when there was none with other versions of Keras/TensorFlow) started immediately after implementing : TFer2 who posted on Jul 6 at 12:48 above.


Thanks very much.

Comment: Does anyone still really think this is a Yahoo historic data problem and that they wouldn't fix all their url's for all their stocks after months of it "not working"? This problem started immediately after following the advice from @TFer2 above.

Can anyone fix this software issues please, this is taking far longer that I could ever have imagined.

Thanks,

Comment: Hi, Is anyone able to figure out why TensorFlow and Keras is causing a fault reading Yahoo historic data? 

The idea that Yahoo would be at fault for months for a myriad of different stocks is frankly ridiculous. 

The problem is the software, particularly as following the recommendations of @TFer2 was when the Yahoo "fault" appeared (instantaneously).

Are there any software specialists with Tensorflow and Keras that can actually get this software to work because I have never ever come across such an intractable problem trying to configure s/ware before. 



Thank you.